# javascript document.write script

Tags: javascript, document.write

Edited qestion

I'm trying to create two separate HTML documents: **main.html** and **sufler.html** . Idea is to control **sufler.html** page from **main.html** . To do that I found a solution
to write sufler's.html code like string element on main.html page, change what I need in that string element and write it with `document.write` function from **main.html** . Everything 
works fine except `<script>` function...

**main.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var HTMLstringPage1     = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link href="stilius.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />',
    HTMLstringPage2     = '</body></html>',
    HTMLstringStyle     = '\x3Cscript type="text/javascript">function styluss(){document.getElementById("flip").style.font="normal normal 30px sans-serif";}\x3C/script>',
    HTMLstringDiv1      = '</head><body onload="styluss()"><div id="sufler"><div id="mov"><p id="flip">',
    HTMLstringDiv2      = '</p></div></div>';

var newWindow           = window.open('sufler.html','_blank','toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, height=615,width=815');

    newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '';
    newWindow.document.write(HTMLstringPage1,HTMLstringDiv1+"Text"+HTMLstringDiv2,HTMLstringPage2); //works fine
//  newWindow.document.write(HTMLstringPage1,HTMLstringStyle,HTMLstringDiv1+"Text"+HTMLstringDiv2,HTMLstringPage2);//works except script function
</script>
```

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically add a script tag, it is much better to do this:

```
var newDoc = newWindow.document;
var script = newDoc.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
var text = newDoc.createTextNode('function styluss(){document.getElementById("flip").style.font="normal normal 30px sans-serif";}');
script.appendChild(text);
newDoc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JqW5F/

---

But, creating code on the fly like this is almost never needed.  Since you must, by definition, generally already know what you want the code to do, you can just have a pre-created function that takes some arguments and then call that existing function with the right arguments to accomplish what you wanted to rather than creating a custom function on the fly:

```
function styleIt(id, fontStyle) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.font = fontStyle;
}

styleIt("flip", "normal normal 30px sans-serif");
styleIt("flip2", "normal normal 12px sans-serif");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will try it. I do this, because as I sed, I'm looking for solution to create and control absolutely new HTML page... So, so far I found just to to this by write all pages code with documen.write function....

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - Once the document has been loaded, `document.write()` will clear the document and start a new one so it is generally not used.  There should be no reason to ever create code with `document.write()` like this.  Just define your own `<script>` tags in the page rather than trying to create code blocks like this.

Comment: I understand you. But idea is to create simple thing: have two separate html pages: main.html and sufler.html In main.html you would write text, change it's style, control text moving speed and all this must be showing in sufler.html... So I found a solution only to create sufler's.html code via string elements and write it with documen.write function...

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - so did either of my two suggestions answer your question?

Comment: Maybe you write everything correct, but it seems I have bigger problems... Because in your case needs to use document.getElementsByTagName but that element is in other html document, and this won't work.. I thing I need to think another question....

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - so use the other document then.  If you want us to help you here, you really have to show us ALL the relevant code.  If you're creating some other browser window and then populating that document, then use that document in my suggested code.

Comment: Here I wrote my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090997/javascript-document-write-new-script

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - you should NOT open a new question just to clarify this one.  Use the "Edit" link to add your code to this question, add a comment to your question saying what you added and delete the [second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090997/javascript-document-write-new-script) you just opened on the same topic.

Comment: Done, sorry for my confus

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - see how I edited my first example to use newWindow.document.

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - here's a working demo of adding a script to the new window: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JqW5F/

Comment: Everything looks nice, just that button: Press here to Execute Dynamically Added Script should be on first page.. second page shouldn't have any buttons.. tiring to do that now, but your's answer seems right :)

Comment: @DenisasTimofijuk - that button is just to show you that the script is there and available to be called.  You would insert your own content into the window.  But that button proves that the script is there and working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use normal opening brackets for `<script>` tags:

```
var HTMLstringStyle = '<script type="text/javascript">function styluss(){document.getElementById("flip").style.font="normal normal 30px sans-serif";}<\/script>';
```

Although I can't see why you would ever use this... attaching a `<script>` tag to the `<head>` or the `<body>` is almost always a superior solution.

Comment: i tried your case.. then it needs to split script end tag: </'+'script> But still it wont do any action I needed... I do this because I'm looking for solution for my project which is to create absolutely new HTML page and I would be able to control it from main.html page....